# Is this an acceptable way for loading data into a static variable?

Tags: c#, .net, static, locking

I have a class which currently reads a web.config file when it is instantiated.

I need to change this logic, so the reading only occurs once (first time an instance is created) and then the data remains static for the lifetime.

So currently, [I have this C# code](https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication/blob/master/Code/SimpleAuthentication.Core/AuthenticationProviderFactory.cs#L10):

```
public AuthenticationProviderFactory()
{
    TraceManager = new Lazy<ITraceManager>(() => new TraceManager()).Value;

    AuthenticationProviders =
        new Lazy<IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>>(
            () => new Dictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>()).Value;

    Initialize();
}
```

Nothing to complex. create the dictionary then initialize it.

To keep things simple (in this SO question) lets just say `Initialize()` just reads data from a web.config file. Grabs data from somewhere and sticks it into the dictionary.

Now I wish to change this, so the first time this class is created, I create the dictionary once (so, it should be static) and then read the data into it, once.

I was thinking of this but not sure if this is acceptable :-

```
private static Lazy<IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>> _authenticationProviders;
private static bool _hasParsedConfigFile = false;

public AuthenticationProviderFactory()
{
    TraceManager = new Lazy<ITraceManager>(() => new TraceManager()).Value;

    _authenticationProviders =
        new Lazy<IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>>(
            () =>
            {
                var authenticationProviders =
                    new Dictionary
                        <string, IAuthenticationProvider>();

                if (!_hasParsedConfigFile)
                {
                    Initialize();
                    _hasParsedConfigFile = true;
                }

                return authenticationProviders;
            });

    Initialize();
}

public static IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider> AuthenticationProviders
{
    get { return _authenticationProviders.Value;  }
}
```

notice how I've think I've made the creation of the Lazy dictionary more .. lazy :P I'm also wondering if a race condition here might cause problems and that I might need double-null locking ... but have heard that double-null locking isn't a very good thread safety / race condition, solution.

Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: you have a bug, the second time this code is executed your dictionary will become empty, because you are returning  `new Dictionary                         <string, IAuthenticationProvider>();`

Comment: also you are calling Initialize twice :)

Comment: as for an answer, make it a static property and do the lazy loding in the get

Comment: yeah, that was just quick editor code as I was thinking out aloud .. but very well spotted! But even if i do the lazy loading in the get .. i could still have multiple requests doing the initialization? or does the `LAZY` part make sure it only happens once. Everything in that scope is .. well .. *locked* ?

Comment: Just curious, but why are you using a `Lazy<T>` then immediately accessing its value?  It's defeating the point of `Lazy<T>`

Comment: Because (i believe) `Lazy<T>` makes the creation of that instance *Thread-Safe* (because of the `ctor` I've used). So I read that as: if 100 requests all hit the service at the same time, 1 of them will do the creation of the object, 99 will wait.. and then blamo! 99 will return the same instance which #1 created. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: If you have that much activity then why would you want to make it lazy.  Just implement a strait up thread safe static.

Comment: Because `Lazy<T>` does the 'locking' part for you, safely. If my understanding of it, is correct.

Comment: @Pure.Krome In the code you show first, this factory is instanced per thread, so I'm confused what you mean. 100 threads at the same time get 100 instances of `AuthenticationProviderFactory`. In the second block with the static dictionary, it will nullref if you don't first create an instance of the factory but access the providers. Very confusing usage. You're MUCH better off with basic singleton/prototype patterns, imo.

Comment: @Marc Ok, so 100 instances are created. that's fine. What is important though, is with these 100 instances .. only the FIRST ONE will do all the heavy lifting. The other 99 will WAIT for the first one to finish. (As opposed to all 100 or most of the 100, doing heavy lifting also which is a waste.) And yep, static property can nullref, so that's been refactored.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to initialize the data in the static constructor which means your code will be

```
static AuthenticationProviderFactory()
{    
    AuthenticationProviders =
        new Lazy<IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>>(
            () => new Dictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>()).Value;

    Initialize();
}
```

but that would not make use of lazy loading as the data will be loaded as soon as the class is being accessed.

so to use lazy loading i suggest a static property like the following:

```
    private readonly object writeLock = new object();
    private static Lazy<IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>> _authenticationProviders;
    private static bool _hasParsedConfigFile = false;
    public static IDictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider> AuthenticationProviders
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_hasParsedConfigFile)
            {
                lock (writeLock)
                {
                    if (!_hasParsedConfigFile)
                    {
                        _authenticationProviders = new Dictionary<string, IAuthenticationProvider>();
                        Initialize();
                        _hasParsedConfigFile = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return _authenticationProviders;
        }
    }
```